# Dialogflow intent is no longer matching on an existing Entity parameter

Tags: dialogflow-es

I had my agent working fine in the Dialogflow console, hitting on my intent training phrases where one of the entity/parameter matchings was a staff name entity. I would run it through the console and it would display the Action Parameter and value correctly. It's been around a week and I when back to the console to add additional training phrases. I simply copied one of the training phrases and pasted it into the "Try it Now" field and now the action no longer hits on the staff parameter.

Any ideas on why I can have training phrases hit on the parameter, but the "Try it now" the the exact same phrase can not?

I tried making changes to the Entity and run it through the learning phase. 
I added a new training phrase and it did automatically pick up the staff entity. Saved it as well and allowed training to complete. Pasted in the exact training phrase to the "Try it now" and again no hit on the action parameter.

[Dialogflow console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSF0f.jpg)
The Diagnostic info basically just showed what the console "Try it now"  window showed.